# Genshin Impact textures load bug on wine

Tags: wine, games

I have a problem running [Genshin Impact](https://genshin.mihoyo.com/en), when I enter the game, the textures turn blue and white. I read on some forums that it's related to RAM on Windows, but I've tried everything so far in Wine, including increasing the RAM assigned to Direct3D, but nothing helps.

My settings:

- OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
- Host: MS-7817 1.0
- Kernel: 5.13.13-1-MANJARO
- Uptime: 6 hours, 24 mins
- Packages: 1266 (pacman)
- Shell: zsh 5.8
- Resolution: 1440x900
- DE: GNOME 40.4
- WM: Mutter
- WM Theme: WhiteSur-dark
- Theme: WhiteSur-dark [GTK2/3]
- Icons: WhiteSur [GTK2/3]
- Terminal: alacritty
- Terminal Font: monospace
- CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1220 v3 (4) @ 3.500GHz
- GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 6570/7570/8550 / R5 230
- Memory: 1929MiB / 9900MiB

Detailed specs [available here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/i1q7oo8p1mkp4p3/myconfigs.txt/file).

Note: I will switch to the Liquorix kernel.

Another note: I usually use my i3 rice, but I tried GNOME to see if the errors disappeared.

A screenshot of the problem:

[image: The image is not mine but the problem is the same as mine]

Comment: What graphics API are you using? Are you just using wine like normal out of the box, or are you using it through some other tool?

Comment: i was using the common opengl, because my gpu doesn't support vulkan to use dxvk